# Unable to install Ubuntu on VAIO laptop

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu on a VAIO laptop and always get this screen.

[image: output]

Can anyone help with explaining what this means?

---

Thank you, for your answer! I did not even manage to get to the Windows desktop, the laptop shuts down unexpectedly during Windows set up. Could it be due to VAIO's strange boot menu, where they offer some Windows recovery options themselves?

When my friend brought this laptop to me, it was on a state where it was not able to recognise the OS (Windows 8 then, Windows 10 is what I reinstalled) and when I reinstalled Windows 10 I found the disk split on 8 partitions! When trying to install Ubuntu with Windows 8, the same error message was coming up.

Do you think that it will work if I remove the HDD, format it using an external HDD case, and then trying again with the internal HDD cleanly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the windows install on your system was not shut down cleanly, or is in 'hibernation / fast startup'. Boot back into Windows, and hold down Shift when clicking on the shutdown button in the start menu. This will suppress the fast startup save state, and shutdown cleanly. Then come back to trying to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! I did not even manage to get to the Windows desktop, the laptop shuts down unexpectedly during Windows set up. Could it be due to VAIO's strange boot menu, where they offer some Windows recovery options themselves?

Comment: When my friend brought this laptop to me, it was on a state where it was not able to recognise the OS (Windows 8 then, Windows 10 is what I reinstalled) and when I reinstalled Windows 10 I found the disk split on 8 partitions! When trying to install Ubuntu with Windows 8, the same error message was coming up.

Do you think that it will work if I remove the HDD, format it using an external HDD case, and then trying again with the internal HDD cleanly formatted?

Comment: This seems a good answer *to the question that you asked*. You neglected to mention all of this important information in your Question, so it's unsurprising that the answer does not help you. Open a new question, ask about your REAL problem, and provide full information.

Comment: If you're not interested in keeping the Windows installation, then sure, taking the drive out and putting in another machine to wipe it is a decent plan.